# Laravel session timeout not working in middleware

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5, middleware, laravel-middleware

Im using laravel 5.8 and im using middleware to check for session timeout. I have mentioned 1hr in my .env for session timeout. My controller works fine and the session variable becomes null but the same session variable in the middleware retains the session value.

Unable to understand the reason.

Im checking the session in the middleware like:

`session('id')`

I have also changes the session value to 1hr in config/app.php

Plz let me know how to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Did you cleared config cache ?

Comment: Where is your middleware declared? Is it a global, grouped or routed? The middleware for StartSession is a grouped, so make sure your runs after StartSession.

Comment: I did clear cache but no good. I forgot to mention 1 thing. My laravel 5.8 have modules and the middleware is implemented under http/middleware which is outside the nwidart modules area. I donot have my middleware in kernal, rather its in route.